# How to use itcl::delegation in TCL?

Tags: tcl, itcl

The following delegation does not work.

How do I get it to work ?

```
package require itcl

itcl::extendedclass Tail {
    method wag {} {
        return "Wag, wag, wag"
    }
}

itcl::extendedclass Dog {
    delegate method wag to tail

    constructor {} {
        set tail [Tail #auto]
    }
}

puts [info patchlevel]
puts $itcl::patchLevel

Dog dog
dog wag
```

Screenshot of error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After poking around, I find that the problem is that the `Tail` instance has been created in the `Dog` namespace (instead of in the instance namespace for `dog` or in the global scope). That's weird, but couples to the fact that the current namespace in the constructor is the `::Dog` namespace. That wouldn't be a problem except Itcl instance construction returns unqualified names and the current namespace when the delegate is processed isn't the same as when the `Tail` instance is made.

My evidence? This:

```
% info class instances Tail
::Dog::tail0
```

But it does suggest that we can fix this by changing the definition of `Dog` to be:

```
itcl::extendedclass Dog {
    delegate method wag to tail

    constructor {} {
        # Convert the name into its fully qualified form right now
        set tail [namespace which [Tail #auto]]
    }
}
```

With that, we can do:

```
% Dog dog
dog
% dog wag
Wag, wag, wag
```

Looks OK to me.

Comment: The problem I see with this solution is that `tail` becomes a static (ie. common / class) variable of `Dog` instead of an instance variable (not sure if this is by design (where `itcl::delegation` creates a static _componentName_)). From my experiments, if I add a constructor parameter "mood" eg: `set tail [namespace which [Tail #auto $mood]]`, then different instances of `Dog` do not delegate their own versions of $mood. On the other hand, it appears that classic delegation via normal methods works ok eg: `variable tail ... set tail [Tail #auto $mood] ... method wag { return [$tail wag] }`.

Comment: I've literally no idea what's going on from your comment. I do know that it's working subtly differently from the equivalent things in TclOO (which I know intimately). I do know that a new Tail will be made for every Dog (and that you _really_ need to use fully qualified names) but don't know what variables get set; my understanding of itcl is rather superficial and their delegation mechanisms are stuff that I've not explored before answering this question. (The first draft of this answer was _totally_ different, and definitely wrong, but fortunately I tested it…)

Comment: I have posted a followup question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68340828/is-an-itcldelegation-component-static-in-tcl.

Comment: Also, in relation to your answer about the namespace issue and Itcl instance construction returning unqualified names - perhaps that is because `delegate method wag to tail` is roughly equivalent to `method wag {args} {uplevel $tail wag $args}` (as mentioned in the documentation https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/ItclCmd/itcldelegate.html#M6).

Comment: The usual complicated bit with all these things is to do with resolution scope, both of commands and of variables, and that's an area where itcl and TclOO definitely do different things. (I only really know the latter, where this whole question would be a forward to a sub-object.)

Comment: But with experimentation, I see that `tail` is being resolved as a class variable. Which seems crazy to me…

Comment: And everything I try is either broken (sharing the most recently-built Tail) or throws an error about undefined components. Huh…