# Is an itcl::delegation component static in TCL?

Tags: tcl, itcl

According to the ITcl man page a delegate method can be declared with `delegate method methodName to componentName ?as targetName?` (https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/ItclCmd/itcldelegate.html#M6).

In the below code, for the `Dog` class there are two variables `tail` and `tail2` that get intialised to a `Tail` object. However only the `wag2` method retains the correct `mood`.

I want to clarify whether the delegation declares component `tail` as a static variable ?

(FYI this is a followup question to a comment from [How to use itcl::delegation in TCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68336192/how-to-use-itcldelegation-in-tcl)).

```
package require itcl

itcl::extendedclass Tail {
    variable mood

    constructor {_mood} {
        set mood $_mood
    }

    method wag {} {
        return "Wag, wag, wag $mood"
    }
}

itcl::extendedclass Dog {
    delegate method wag to tail

    variable tail2

    constructor {mood} {
        set tail  [namespace which [Tail #auto $mood]]    ;#// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68336192/how-to-use-itcldelegation-in-tcl
        set tail2 [Tail #auto $mood]
    }

    method wag2 {} {
        return [$tail2 wag]
    }
}

puts [info patchlevel]
puts $itcl::patchLevel

Dog happydog :)
Dog saddog   :(

puts [happydog wag]
puts [saddog   wag]

puts [happydog wag2]
puts [saddog   wag2]
```

Expected:

```
Wag, wag, wag :)
Wag, wag, wag :(
Wag, wag, wag :)
Wag, wag, wag :(
```

Actual:

```
Wag, wag, wag :(    <==== note: happydog is not happy
Wag, wag, wag :(
Wag, wag, wag :)
Wag, wag, wag :(
```

Screenshot of output (that shows only the `wag2` call retains correct `mood`):

[image]